# Styling the span in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have bought a template with a tab tour element (kind of a menu that unfolds different content) and I wanted to change the color of the text inside the list.
Each and every tab needs to have a different color. So first one red, second blue, third green and fourth yellow. I tried everything with childs, element, classes etc. but no result.

Here is one of the codes I tried

```css
#one a
{
color:#e28844
}
```

```html
<ul class='cmsms_tabs_list'>
  <li id="one" class="cmsms_tabs_list_item">
     <a href="#">
       <span>One</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <li id="two" class="cmsms_tabs_list_item">
     <a href="#">
       <span>Two</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <li id="three" class="cmsms_tabs_list_item">
     <a href="#">
       <span>Three</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <li id="four" class="cmsms_tabs_list_item">
     <a href="#">
       <span>Four</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: weird in the template it didn't. I see what you mean

Comment: The template might have overriding CSS code. So you need to post the full code that is affecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following style

```
.cmsms_tabs_list li:nth-of-type(1) a span {
     color : red;
}

.cmsms_tabs_list li:nth-of-type(3) a span {
      color : blue;
}

.cmsms_tabs_list li:nth-of-type(4) a span {
      color : green;
}

.cmsms_tabs_list li:nth-of-type(2) a span {
      color : yellow;
}
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/s1s12w2x/1/

Comment: in this way it doesnt work, but I placed span behind it and it works! thanks

Comment: Great it worked. I have updated the answer to include span, though, it worked for me without span